# Failed to train toy LSTM in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to get acquainted with recurrent networks in tensorflow using a toy problem for sequence classification.

Data:

```
half_len = 500
pos_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # Positive sequence.
neg_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] # Negative sequence.
num_input = len(pos_ex)
data = np.concatenate((np.stack([pos_ex]*half_len), np.stack([neg_ex]*half_len)), axis=0)
labels = np.asarray([0, 1] * half_len + [1, 0] * half_len).reshape((2 * half_len, -1))
```

Model:

```
_, x_width = data.shape
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, x_width])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, n_hidden]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden]))


def lstm_model():
    from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
    x = tf.split(X, num_input, 1)
    rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + bias
```

Training:

```
logits = lstm_model()
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

# Train...
```

My training accuracy varies around 0.5, which confuses me because the problem is very simple.

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss = 82.2726, Training Accuracy = 0.453
Step 25, Minibatch Loss = 6.7920, Training Accuracy = 0.547
Step 50, Minibatch Loss = 0.8528, Training Accuracy = 0.500
Step 75, Minibatch Loss = 0.6989, Training Accuracy = 0.500
Step 100, Minibatch Loss = 0.6929, Training Accuracy = 0.516
```

Changing the toy data to:

```
pos_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
neg_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]
```

Yields an instant convergence to accuracy 1. Could anyone please explain me why this network fails on such a simple task? Thank you.

The code above is based on [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reducing the learning rate?
In the second example the separation on the last coordinate is larger in values, which should make no difference, but **has effect on the choice of learning rate**.
If you would normalize the data (set the domain of each coordinate between -1 and 1), and find the appropriate *step size*, you should solve both problems in the same number of steps.

**EDIT**: Played with your toy examples a little, the following is working even without normalization

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

# Meta parameters

n_hidden = 10
num_classes = 2
learning_rate = 1e-2
input_dim = 5
num_input = 5



# inputs
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, input_dim])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])

# Model
def lstm_model():
    # input layer
    x = tf.split(X, num_input, 1)

    # LSTM layer
    rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # final layer - softmax
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, num_classes]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + bias

# logits and prediction
logits = lstm_model()
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)


# -----------
# Train func
# -----------
def train(data,labels):

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(1000):
            _, loss, onehot_pred = session.run([train_op, loss_op, prediction], feed_dict={X: data, Y: labels})
            acc = np.mean(np.argmax(onehot_pred,axis=1) == np.argmax(labels,axis=1))
            print('Iteration {} accuracy: {}'.format(i,acc))
            if acc == 1:
                print('---> Finised after {} iterations'.format(i+1))
                break

# -----------
# Train 1
# -----------
# data generation
half_len = 500
pos_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # Positive sequence.
neg_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] # Negative sequence.



data = np.concatenate((np.stack([pos_ex]*half_len), np.stack([neg_ex]*half_len)), axis=0)
labels = np.asarray([0, 1] * half_len + [1, 0] * half_len).reshape((2 * half_len, -1))

train(data,labels)

# -----------
# Train 2
# -----------
# data generation
half_len = 500
pos_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # Positive sequence.
neg_ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100] # Negative sequence.


data = np.concatenate((np.stack([pos_ex]*half_len), np.stack([neg_ex]*half_len)), axis=0)
labels = np.asarray([0, 1] * half_len + [1, 0] * half_len).reshape((2 * half_len, -1))

train(data,labels)
```

Output is:

```
Iteration 0 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 1 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 2 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 3 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 4 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 5 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 6 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 7 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 8 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 9 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 10 accuracy: 1.0
---> Finised after 11 iterations

Iteration 0 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 1 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 2 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 3 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 4 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 5 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 6 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 7 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 8 accuracy: 0.5
Iteration 9 accuracy: 1.0
---> Finised after 10 iterations
```

Good luck!

Comment: Simple as that... Learning rate fixed it and normalization is a good point. Thank you for your help and sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: @Gerry no problem, things sometimes seem to be complicated although they are not.... I am experiencing some annoying issues when doing reinforcement learning on my problems now... Its a pain... Always minor issues cause the biggest troubles.